# there is no error and it works but cant find data in calendar

Tags: android, calendar

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setEvent();
}
private void setEvent(){  

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
    intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
    intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
    intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
    startActivity(intent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Event Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   }}
```

this code is adding data on calendar.
I found it and I tried and no error founded and it works well because I got a toast. but I cant find any new event on my calendar.
How can I do? do I have to add more codes?
or is it not working on google calendar? 
Please help me to add event on calendar. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass value as below :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, strTitle);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,startDateMillis);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,endDateMillis);
intent.putExtra(Events.ALL_DAY, false);// periodicity
intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION,strDescription));
startActivity(intent);
```

More parameter Ref. :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

Comment: Thank you very much!! but I want to add automatically.. not new adding page. just add automatically on calendar on the date that I wrote in the code,, can I do?